# Get Join table data as a result of ActiveRecord:Relation

Tags: oracle, join, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using rails 5 and oracle as a database. My query look like this..

```
DefaultConfig.where("role_id = ?","1001").joins(:config_param)
```

Now i want to get the result object as a `config_param` object not a `default_config`..
is it possible to do? Thanks for any help

```
class DefaultConfig < ApplicationRecord
    self.table_name = "default_config"
    belongs_to :role
    belongs_to :config_param
end

class ConfigParam < ApplicationRecord
    self.table_name = "config_param"  
    has_many :default_configs, foreign_key: "param_id"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ConfigParam.joins(:default_configs).where(default_config: { role_id: 1001 })
```

Comment: i already try this.. but dont know why it is giving error like
`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: OCIError: ORA-00904: "DEFAULT_CONFIGS"."ROLE_ID": invalid identifier: SELECT "CONFIG_PARAM".* FROM "CONFIG_PARAM" INNER JOIN
 "DEFAULT_CONFIG" ON "DEFAULT_CONFIG"."PARAM_ID" = "CONFIG_PARAM"."ID" WHERE "DEFAULT_CONFIGS"."ROLE_ID" = :a1` and columns in default configs are
`DefaultConfig.new
#<DefaultConfig id: nil, role_id: nil, param_id: nil, default_value: nil, order: nil>`

Comment: @user9392255 please show me the model associations. ALso, reload the console (log out and log in again)

Comment: @user9392255 in the `joins` part you have to mention the association name (singular or plural depending on association) and in the `where` part you have to pass the database table name (despite of how the model is called). In your case the table is called `default_config` even though the association is `has_many :default_configs`. So changing htat to `default_config` in the `where` does the trick.